# xaml Binding to enum. Display value instead of "ToString"

Tags: wpf, xaml, enums, binding

I have a property of an enum type. I bind the content of a wpf control to this property. This will display the name of the enum value. So the ToString Method of enum is called.

But I need to display the value, not the string value. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is my C# code:

```
public enum Animal 
{ 
   cat = 0, 
   dog = 1, 
   mouse = 2 
}

public Animal MyAnimal { get; set; } 

void SomeMethod() { MyAnimal = dog; }
```

This is in my XAML:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyAnimal}">
```

Comment: what value do u need to show?

Comment: in order u want to display the int/double/short etc value of enum, pls consider to use the value converter and simple cast rhe enum to its specific value. like that (int/double/short)EnumName.EnumStringValue.

Comment: Please post your code that doesn't work. Also try `<Label Content="{Binding Visibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>` as an example which shows that it does work out of the box.

Comment: <!-- language: c# -->
    public enum Animal
    {
      cat = 0,
      dog = 1,
      mouse = 2
    }


    public Animal MyAnimal {get; set;}

    void SomeMethod()
    {
       MyAnimal = dog;
    }

<!-- language: xaml -->
    <Label Content="{Binding MyAnimal}">


The Label sould no display 1 instead of dog

Comment: grrr... I do not understand how to format code. And there is also no preview to test.

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting code in a comment.

Comment: As mentioned, either use a converter or return an actual int from your source property.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind to a value of one type and want to display it in another format than the default ToString() method provides you should either use a DataTemplate or an IValueConverter. Since XAML is a *markup* language you cannot really cast the enumeration value to an int in your markup so you should use a converter:

```
public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        animals enumValue = (animals)value;
        return System.Convert.ToInt32(enumValue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

<Window.Resources>
    <local:EnumConverter x:Key="conv" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<ContentControl Content="{Binding TheEnumProperty, Converter={StaticResource conv}}" />
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer mm8. This works. But now I have an additional question.
I have to display values from a database. This values I have mapped to an enum. And I want to display this values with its names. But if I recieve a value from database which is not defined in the enum I need to display its value. If I just bind to the enum property, and the property has a value outside the range nothing is displayed. If i use the converter. Always the value is displayed.

Comment: This is a certainly a different requirement than your original one...I don't understand how you set the enum source property to a value from the database that doesn't exist in the enum because this won't even compile...?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (!(value is Enum)) return value;

    return Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value) ? value : System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
```